# How can spirituality be reliably researched?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, belief, methodology, action

My questions are
1 is there a reliable method for research into spiritual activity such as an individual providing healing, or any other service?
2 is there a ‘happy medium’ pardon the pun, that’s acceptable?

Most research into spiritual belief leading to action, such as spiritual healing based on the belief in an energy that is benevolent and can be directed to heal an individual, is based on anecdotes or positive case studies.
Problems of course arise from ignoring negative evidence, putting non-healing down to the will of the higher authority, and so on.
I would like to do more than just describe or analyse what people believe is happening, while recognising reporting bias.
Empirical science appears incompatible with inquiry into this area, since it is unable to acknowledge philosophical belief, while usual qualitative research approaches do not allow for generalisation to the wider population.
I’ve looked at individual account narratives, case studies and research based on questionnaires but I don’t like them. They do not seem robust enough.

Comment: Health effects experiments involving spiritually based medicine effects are as readily evaluated as basically any other medical treatment.  And those studies are being done.  For example, here is a meta-study -- summarizing the effects found in the cumulative data set available on one spiritual method -- Reiki: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5871310/

Comment: What's the question? The OPs standard seems to be: No method is reliable unless it confirms my belief in spiritual healing.

Comment: Re your "I’ve looked at individual account narratives, case studies and research based on questionnaires but I don’t like them". Now *suppose* you finally find or arrive at a reliable research system of spirituality, but then someone else after reviewing it could conceivably say the same conclusion "but I don't like them...", and does "like" belong to your definitional scope of spirituality? If so there seems a logical paradox here. If it doesn't belong to spirituality, then it seems "like/dislike" should be in eliminative neuroscientific scope, then what else in spirituality can escape?...